# Save all files content from a directory and sub directory into a single file with Windows cmd/Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

So, I have a folder with sub folders with files of different types (php,js,html). I would like to know if there is a command on windows powershell/cmd to save all files content of my directory into a single file. In brief, I would like to do a recursive cat > save.txt on windows.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to recursively discover any files in the folder hierarchy, then pipe those to `Get-Content` (for reading) and finally pipe the output from those calls to `Set-Content` (for writing the whole thing back to disk).

```
Get-ChildItem path\to\root\folder -Recurse -File |Get-Content |Set-Content path\to\save.txt
```

Note: Unlike `cat`, `Get-Content` reads the files as text/strings by default, so this will work well for text-encoded files (like js, php and html source files), but won't work on binary files

Answer (score 1):

From the **command prompt**:

You can use the copy command with the `+` character to concatenate multiple files:

`copy file1.txt + file2.txt save.txt`.

To concatenate all files in a directory use the for command in combination with `dir /b` (/b means bare format, only files names)

`for /f %f in ('dir *.* /b') do @type %f>>save.txt`

Or recursively, using `/s` for directory and all subdirectories in combination with `/a:-d` to exclude directories in the output.

`for /f %f in ('dir *.* /b /s /a:-d') do @type %f>>save.txt`

Using **PowerShell**:

Concatenate list of files:

`Get-Content .\file1.txt,.\file2.txt | Out-File Save.txt`

Concatenate all files in a directory:

`(Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ } ) | out-file save.txt`

Concatenate all files recursively:

`(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_.FullName } ) | out-file save.txt`

Note: for binary files you may want to add the `/b` switch to the `copy` command or if using PowerShell add `-Raw` to `Get-Content`